# In template of the directive i had added the click event which was handling in the link .But the issue is that the function is calling two times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

this is my directive .IN this i had added the ng-click for the li with the display of the item name but the function is calling for two times .Any one can you please explain it was happening .below  the  code jsfiddle link is available for my issue

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',       
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            combo: '=combo'
        },
        template: '<ul ng-repeat="comboCollection in combo.comboCollections">'+'<li ng-click="testing(comboCollection.comboItemName)">'+
        '<label>'+
        '<input type="radio" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" ng-show="comboCollection.havingSub" id={{comboCollection.comboItemCode}} ng-checked="true">'+
        '{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}'+'</label>'+
        '</li>' +'<li ng-repeat="substitute in combo.itemSubstitutes" ng-show="substitute.forItem==comboCollection.comboItemCode" ng-click="testing(substitute.subItemName)">'+
        '<label>'+
        '<input type="radio" id="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}"  value="{{substitute.subItemName}}">'+'{{substitute.subItemName}}'+'</label>'+'</li>'+'</ul>',
        link:function(scope) {
            scope.testing=function(code){
                console.log("details");
                alert(code);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/taheerahamed/Ajsy7/9/

Comment: In chrome, it is only firing once.  Could be a Firefox issue?

Comment: For me, the function is only firing once on both Chrome and Firefox so not sure what the issue is. On a (maybe) unrelated note, your HTML markup looks really weird, (ng-repeat on <ul> and then again on one children <li>). Mind posting your template HTML separately?

Comment: It fires twice for me in Chrome